# How to pass data continuously between two independent class in react js?

Tags: reactjs

So i have a search field sitting in my header class and i want to pass the search value to the content which is sitting in another class so can anyone tell how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the purpose of redux and having a global state. You can check out a starter react redux project I built for more details. But basically you will need to dispatch actions which will update the global state from one class and then is accessible by all other components in your app.

https://github.com/iqbal125/modern-react-app-sample